# Is specifying the partition key in the SQL equivalent to using FeedOptions.PartitionKey?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

Using the SQL api you can specify the partition key in the SQL statement e.g. `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.MyPartitionKey = 'KeyValue'` or using `FeedOptions.PartitionKey`.

Are they equivalent or will one way have a lower RU cost?

I have tried both ways and can't see a difference but the data set is quite small and this may change as the data grows over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some tests.

***Test One:*** 100 documents

```
for (int i = 1; i <=100 ; i++) {
     Document doc = new Document();
     doc.setId(i + "");
     if(i%2 == 0)
        doc.set("name", "white");
     else
        doc.set("name", "black");
     documentClient.createDocument("dbs/db/colls/part", doc, null, true);
     System.out.println("insert document No. " + i);
}
```

query 1:

```
String sql ="SELECT * FROM c where c.name='black'";
FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions();
FeedResponse<Document> queryResults = documentClient.queryDocuments("dbs/db/colls/part",sql,options);
System.out.println(queryResults.getRequestCharge());
```

result: `17.44` RUs

---

query 2:

```
FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions();
PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey("black");
options.setPartitionKey(partitionKey);
String sql ="SELECT * FROM c";
FeedResponse<Document> queryResults = documentClient.queryDocuments("dbs/db/colls/part",sql,options);
System.out.println(queryResults.getRequestCharge());
```

result: `17.44` RUs

***Test Two:*** 1000 documents

```
for (int i = 1; i <=1000 ; i++) {
         Document doc = new Document();
         doc.setId(i + "");
         if(i%2 == 0)
            doc.set("name", "white");
         else
            doc.set("name", "black");
         documentClient.createDocument("dbs/db/colls/part", doc, null, true);
         System.out.println("insert document No. " + i);
}
```

query 1 & 2 are both `31.57` RUs

As mentioned in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#estimating-throughput-needs), the `RUS` is related to the operating document size or concurrent throughput. The above two query result sets are not different, so  they should have the same RU cost.

Comment: That's the same result as I've observed so far.

Answer (score 2):

Both are equivalent and should have the same RU cost.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back up this answer?